# how to expose spring data nesting endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data

I'm using spring-data with mongoDB, and exposing an REST endpoint for a collection was simple, just following the tutorial, I was able to implement an interface like:

```
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String> {
}
```

And everything just works like expected. But what I want to do now, is to expose an endpoint like this: GET /book/1/authors. How to do that with spring-data?

Comment: You should use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations in `Book` and `Author` entities to define a relationship between these two models

Comment: I know that you can use these annotations with spring-data with jpa, does it apply to mongoDB as well?